# Find parameters so that random variables (connected to Brownian movement) are independent.

Tags: random-variables, solution-verification, brownian-motion

$W_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t)$ is Brownian movement, find values of parameters $a, b$ for which $aW_1-W_2$ and $W_3+bW_5$ are independent.

I don't even know where to start, so any hint is highly appreciated, though that's my ''solution''.

Do I have to find $\mathrm{Cov}(aW_1-W_2,W_3+bW_5)=0$?

If so then

$\mathrm{Cov}(aW_1-W_2,W_3+bW_5)$
$=a\mathrm{Cov}(W_1,W_3)+ab\mathrm{Cov}(W_1,W_5)+\mathrm{Cov}(-W_2,W_3)+b\mathrm{Cov}(-W_2,W_5)$
$=a+ab-2-2b$
Hence $a=2,\ b=-1$

Is this the **right solution**? I would be grateful if you could point out every mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that jointly normal random variables are independent iff they are uncorrelated.  So yes, you find the covariance, and yes, it is $a + ab - 2 - 2b$.  And since $a + ab - 2 - 2b = (a-2)(1+b)$, the answer is $a=2$ **or** $b=-1$ (the way you wrote it, it looks like you want $a=2$ **and** $b=-1$, but that is overkill).

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed you have to find a,b such that

$$cov(aW_1-W_2,W_3+bW_5)=0$$
Because you know that $(W_1,W_2,W_3,W_5)$ follows a normal distribution.
Hence $(aW_1-W_2,W_3+bW_5)$ also follows a normal distribution. Now, we know that for normal distributed variables , independence holds if and only if the covariance between them is 0.

Comment: ... for **jointly** normal random variables.  It is easy to construct counterexamples where the individual random variables are normal but the joint distribution is not.

Comment: Of course. Thanks